# centering of content horizontal and vertical in a fixed Dimensional div

Tags: jquery, css, vertical-alignment, centering, alignment

I want to to have content like below 

[image: 1]
for this first one I used line-height 40px

[image]
for the second one I used line-height 120px

**This means as content varies I have to change the line-heights 
Is there any way to make this type of centering in a fixed dimensional div without 
changing the class**

Can I do this without Javascript ? 
If I use height as 120px I am getting div s like this ( I dont want this ) 
[image]

style of the div is

```
<style>
 .rectangle {
        postion:absolute;
    box-shadow: 10px #333;
    border-radius: 23px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border:6px solid;
    block:inline;
    line-height: 123.6px;
    width:200px;
    background-color: #444;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
   font-weight:900;

    text-decoration:none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: can we see the code u did...?

Comment: Thanks for comment .I have added the css style of that

Comment: http://css.flepstudio.org/en/css-tutorials/centered-vertical-horizontal-align.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421334/vertical-and-horizontal-align-middle-and-center-with-css

Comment: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Comment: Additionally there is no such thing as position: absolute and float: left. Float & Positioning dont work together.

Comment: block:inline; ? There is no such property. Maybe display: block;, display: inline-block;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertical centring is tricky. Chris Coyier at CSS tricks has a great article on this - http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

My personal preference is the ghost pseudo element, but it's only viable in IE8+ so you may need to look at some of the other examples if legacy IE support is necessary.

Here's a working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tommarshall/eGJQC/3/

Answer (score 1):

Make .rectangle element to be displayed as table, and the inner text paragraph to be displayed as a table cell. Then you can easily vertical position your paragraph.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ktzUn/

Comment: Note this does not work in IE7 and under, and IE8 exhibits strange behaviours with `display:table;`

Comment: With the increase in the content the height of the div is increasing http://jsfiddle.net/ktzUn/

Comment: David, it's true about IE7 and below; IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE.
Madhu13, what did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

following css works properly even if height and the content in div varies

```
.rectangle 
      {
        height:auto;
        postion:absolute;
        box-shadow: 10px #333;
        border-radius: 23px;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
        border:6px solid;
        block:inline;
        width:200px;
        background-color: #444;
        float: left; padding:20px 10px 20px 10px;
        margin: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        color:white;
        font-weight:900;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
```

Comment: block:inline is for changing the block element to inline element http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: block:inline; ? There is no such property. Maybe display: block;, display: inline-block;

Answer (score 0):

Vertical alignment works perfectly only in table>tr>td. for others you can also try giving padding from top and bottom. that doesn't need any vertical alignment and would work simply best.

Thanks
Rahul