# CSS Using position relative+absolute or negative margin

Tags: css, position, css-position, margin

I want to put a small div (50x50) on the center of another div (200x200).

I got 2 ways to do it:

[Using position absolute and relative](http://jsfiddle.net/WrAFB/)

```
position:relative
position:absolute
top:75px;
left:75px;
```

or

[Using negaive margin](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9LFY/1/)

```
margin:-125px 0 0 75px;
```

I would like to know which way is better and why...
I heard some people saying that position is not recommended.. is that true? why?

**EDIT:**
The divs are exmaples.
In reality I got image above another image (youtube preview image, and play button image above it).
The Images are inside accordion, and in ie6 closing the accordion/open it cause the absolute container to float above everything...

Comment: There is no problem with `position` at all. It has "side-effects" of course, but if you are aware of them, you should use them where appropriate. Voted to close the question as "not constructive".

Comment: [vertical and horizontal align (middle and center) with css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421334/vertical-and-horizontal-align-middle-and-center-with-css).

Comment: @Vucko the divs are examples. in reality I got img above another img.. can use the solution in ur link.

Comment: Is IE6 support essential? It's currently sitting at 0.6% usage and dropping. The cost to support it across an application is way more than it's worth. http://www.w3counter.com/trends

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using `absolute` and `relative` positioning, they have been fully supported for a long time. Of your two methods I would definitely go with the absolute and relative position one as the margin one is a little hacky.

Personally I would use neither of your methods and instead put `#small` inside `#big` as it is a little more semantically correct (because `#small` is within `#big`).

[See on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GfD8S/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="con">
    <div id="big">
        <div id="small"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#big {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
}
#small {
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin-left:-25px;
    margin-top:-25px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    background:blue;
}
```

Comment: the divs are just examples. in reality I got img above another img. cant use your build anyway..

Comment: Definitely go with absolute positioning then.

Answer (score 1):

Using margin is better !
If you use

```
position:relative
position:absolute
```

You need understand correlative with div outside

Answer (score 1):

Position is not recommended for people who don't know how to use it, for the rest of us, it works perfectly fine.

I would definitely not use a negative margin.. like Tyriar [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15309269/766570) it's hacky and also it's not easy to read.

as for the ie6 bug, you there are bugs aplenty with ie's, the way to address them is by complimenting your otherwise sound html/css with fail safe code, rather than degenerating your sound html into hacky html for ie's sake.

Answer (score 0):

i had same challenge in my previous project, where i had to choose to between position absolute + relative and negative margin, and i had seen that when we use negative margin it's way more easier to maintain design for responsiveness, and also when design are bit complex and needs to be responsive using negative margin is good option whereas design are simple using relative + absolute goes fine.