# How to horizontally and vertically center align the text in the div?

Tags: css

How can we center (horizontally and vertically) the text in this div?

HTML

```
<div class="text">   
hello is the the testhello is the the testhello is the the testhello is the the testhello is the the testhello is the the    
testhello is the the tes   
</div>
```

CSS

```
.text {
    width:150px; 
    background:red;
    float:left;
    height:150px;
    margin:10px; 
    text-align:center;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    overflow:hidden;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: [This should answer your question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421334/vertical-and-horizontal-align-middle-and-center-with-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the full explanation here. Read this.

http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

If you want to vertical & horizontal center to unknown height, width element. you must add the style for parent as display:table and the style for child as display:table-cell.

//UPDATED

if you know the height & width of the element.

Try this.

```
.parent {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
}

.child {
  display:block;
  height:x;
  width:y;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top:-x/2; //Half of the height with minus direction
  margin-left:-y/2; //Half of the width with minus direction
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why you have not used text-align:center?

Comment: Text-align:center only work for horizontal. but if you want to be align vertical-center. you must add the style as display:table-cell to the element. Vertical align only work for **display:table-cell**. And Display:table-cell only work inside **display:table;**

Answer (score 1):

Example on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BFqfx/

```
div {
  width:150px; 
  height:150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  background:red;   
  color: #fff;
}

div p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

---

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Where is the p tag, in html body, inside div?

Comment: what about my float:left;word-wrap:break-word;overflow:hidden;?

Comment: I've just removed for simplicity. Add all the style you want

Comment: your code does work in the CodePen, however wont work in my IE/Chrome, text not aligned horiz/vert.

Comment: this is the codepen with all the style http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iupys/ and it works still fine on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kSxD3/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="foo">
   <div class="bar">
       Unknown stuff to be centered.
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.foo{
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
}
.bar {
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[Article](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)**

Answer (score 0):

There is another common technique, based upon "absolute positioning" and negative top margin.

HTML:

```
<div class="foo">
   <div class="bar">
       Unknown stuff to be centered.
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.foo{
   width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
}
.bar {
   text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    height:40px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    border:solid 1px blue;
}
```

The idea is that you move down to 50% from the top the inner div, and then push it up of half its height with negative margin-top.

*Is very stable and cross-platform, the only constraint is **you must know height of inner div**.*

To avoid this costraint, a workaround is replacing negative `margin-top` with a `transform: translateY(-50%);`. In this case, negative translation to center DIV is obtained visually with CSS transformation.

*It's useful because in this way **you can use it without knowing height of inner DIV**, but remember that transformation are extracted from DOM rendering.*

Comment: I want height of the div to be 150*150 max

Comment: Ok.... you can simply set inner div to have width and height of 150px, and then apply a bigger width and height to the container. The principle is the same.