# CSS not working in IE and Chrome, but works in CodePen via Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

We have CSS and html which does not work when we open in IE or Chrome. Text is not center aligned.

However, it works when run via Chrome-> [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fAozd/), Text is center aligned.

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
div {
  float:left;margin-left:10px;word-wrap:break-word;overflow:hidden;
 width:150px; 
 height:150px;
 line-height: 150px;
 background:red;   
 color: #fff;
}

div p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div>
<p>
hello is the the testhello is the the testhello is the the testhello
  </p>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

My local machine Chrome:

[image]

Comment: In chrome for osx the text is center aligned (in both codepen and locally), which version of chrome are you testing on?

Comment: version 34.0.1847.116

Comment: Hmmm same one I'm using, are you able to post a screenshot?

Comment: updated with image, same thing with IE 11.0.9600

Answer (score 2):

IF you want to use **Vertical-align** for a element, that display must be table-cell.

Check this. Working fine.

```
div {
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:150px; 
  height:150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  background:red;   
  color: #fff;
  display:table;
}

div p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: hey, that works.! Thanks, but my the question here is different. Maybe you can answer the same here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012932/how-to-horizontally-and-vertically-center-align-the-text-in-the-div and I will mark it answered.

Comment: If I use this code, and the p tag has data without spaces then the div width increases. How to prevent this?

Comment: Just add this style to p tag **word-wrap: break-word;** .. Read this article on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap

Comment: Yes, besides this, I had to add to the p tag --> max-width:150px.

Comment: Check the code by entering data into P tag like "testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest" It will auto inc width of div. Hence, solution is to set max-width:150px for the p tag.