# Centering span near an image with the respect to the wrapper div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

How do I both vertically and horizontally center the span element without using tables?

I need the picture on the left and thereafter the span aligned in center of the wrapper `div`. The span element should not be aligned in between the `img` and right side, but the whole `div` itself.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8ESb/626/)

```html
<div style="height: 100px; background-color:black;color:white;">
  <img style="height:100px;" src="http://www.kiplinger.com/quiz/business/T049-S001-test-your-start-up-know-how/images/all-small-businesses-have-to-be-incorporated1.jpg">
  <span class="hejsa">hej du</span>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no span elemnt in fiddle??

Comment: This question has been asked several times before on SO. Have you given them a try?

Comment: Tried a bunch, couldn't seem to get it working, just looking for a straight down working code snippet that will allow me to do this, without big position: changes.

Comment: Do you mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/e8ESb/627/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e8ESb/628/
@RasmusHjorthLudeking

Comment: possible duplicate of [vertical and horizontal align (middle and center) with css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421334/vertical-and-horizontal-align-middle-and-center-with-css)

Comment: Hashem, thanks - but not quiet. I need the picture on the left and thereafter the span aligned in center of page.

Comment: Abdul thx, but this makes the span element align centered in between the img and right side - I need the span centered with respect to the whole site.

Comment: Is supporting IE8 and olders a concern?

Comment: Nope not at all. Just need support on all up to date browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP stated:

> I need the span centered with respect to the whole site.

One option could be to position the `<span>` element `absolute`ly and align the text to the center horizontally and vertically as follows:

#### Method #1:

Using `top`/`left` and `transform` properties:

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px; background-color:black; color:white;
}

.wrapper > span.hejsa {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img style="height:100px;" src="http://www.kiplinger.com/quiz/business/T049-S001-test-your-start-up-know-how/images/all-small-businesses-have-to-be-incorporated1.jpg" />
    <span class="hejsa">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    </span>
</div>
```

It's worth noting that [CSS transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/) is [not supported in IE8 and olders](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) <sup>(which is not the OP's concern as s/he mentioned in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821510/centering-span-inside-div/26821683#comment42212684_26821510))</sup>

#### Method #2:

Expanding the absolutely positioned `<span>` element by `top`/`right`/`bottom`/`left` properties:

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px; background-color:black; color:white;
}

/* .wrapper > img { position: relative; z-index: 1; } */ /* optional */

.wrapper > span.hejsa {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img style="height:100px;" src="http://www.kiplinger.com/quiz/business/T049-S001-test-your-start-up-know-how/images/all-small-businesses-have-to-be-incorporated1.jpg" />
    <span class="hejsa">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    </span>
</div>
```

This method has a wider browser support, however one drawback of it is the text should **not** be multiline.

Comment: just for knowledge, @hashem why use transform and css3 properties when this can be done with css? that will run on old browsers as well?

Comment: @AbdulBasit Just noticed your answer +1 It's better than mine. However I'm not sure if removing the image from normal flow is okay to OP as it could affect the other elements (if any). I'll delete my answer if the OP accepts yours, respectively.

Comment: no it is okay  i was just learning from your code, problem is solved thats pretty good :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

css

```
div{text-align:center;line-height:100px;position:relative;}
img{position:absolute;left:0}
```

html

```
<div style="height: 100px; background-color:black;color:white;"><img style="height:100px;" src="http://www.kiplinger.com/quiz/business/T049-S001-test-your-start-up-know-how/images/all-small-businesses-have-to-be-incorporated1.jpg"><span class="hejsa">hej du</span></div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8ESb/631/)

Comment: Note that `align` attribute is deprecated since HTML4.01 and obsoleted since HTML5.

Comment: @AbdulBasit I put your code in a code snippet which runs right on Stack Overflow - why did you move it into a jsfiddle?

Comment: But.. this makes the span element align with respect to the space between left edge and picture.

Comment: @nathan accidently, we were both editing at the same time, how can i go to that again?

Comment: @AbdulBasit Oh ok, that's fine :) Just rollback the edit (click "edited x mins ago" and click "rollback" on my edit with code snippet). For more info about code snippets, checkout [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: @RasmusHjorth yes as img also occupies the space, do you want to center it as whole?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Keep the img on the left - BUT center the span with respect to the whole page.